# Ruby on Rails проблемы с установкой gem best_in_place

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Помогите разобраться в чем проблема - добавить в проект `best_in_place gem`.
Согласно [документации](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) добавил в Gemfile следующее:

```
gem 'best_in_place', '~> 3.0.1'
```

После добавляю в `application.js` следующие:

```
//= require best_in_place
//= require jquery-ui
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
```

Полностью мой application.js выглядит следующим образом:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs   
//= require best_in_place
//= require jquery-ui
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

В файл `tasks.coffe` так же добавлено следующее:

```
 jQuery ->
      $('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
```

В результате ошибка:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Tasks#index

Showing /Users/alexandr.dmitrenko/tasklist/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

couldn't find file 'best_in_place' with type 'application/javascript'
```

[image: Проблема установки best_in_place gem]

Comment: ...а `bundle install` сделали?

Comment: Да установил - Using best_in_place 3.1.0, не могу понять что не так делаю и где искать решение(

Comment: Как ввариант - https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/best_in_place.js - скопировать туда, куда просит Sprockets

Comment: Не совсем понял, что куда скопировать нужно( Пожалуйста для особо одаренных подскажите подробней

Comment: ...просто прикиньтесь для рельс, что это **ваш** код и обращайтесь с ним соответственно. Но вообще это нехорошо и надо как минимум воспроизвести на минимальном приложении. Как-нибудь займусь.

Comment: В `app/assets/javascripts`.

Answer (score 1):

**Решение проблемы:**

1. Добавить в Gemfile: `gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.5'`
2. Выполнить `bundle install`
3. Перезапустить сервер

И последнее открываем нужное нам View и вставляем:

```
<%= best_in_place task, :name %>
```

Comment: Какая-то свалка слабосвязанных действий ._. По меньшей мере код контроллера к ликвидации проблемы не имеет отношения.

Comment: Код контроллера убрал. На счет не упорядоченности действий - если изначально в Gemfile не стоит `gem 'jquery-ui-rails' ` , то после перезагрузки сервера будет ошибка. Для корректной работы нужен `gem 'jquery-ui-rails' `. Поэтому на мой взгляд последовательность правильно указана.

Comment: Решение всё равно кажется странным, в ридми гема отдельно сказано, что jQuery UI **необязателен**. К сожалению, при попытке это воспроизвести я **убил себе виртуалку** (чем-то несвязанным) и на восстановление потребуется время %) Но минус снял, это уже лучше.